# Junit fails for ExchangeFilterFunction

Tags: java, junit5

I am getting below exception for Junit test. I am unsure what I am making wrong.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ExchangeFilterFunction must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClientBuilder.filter(DefaultWebClientBuilder.java:197)
at com.mt.common.webclient.WebClientHelper.webClientBuilder(WebClientHelper.java:327)
at com.mt.common.webclient.WebClientHelper.performWebRequest(WebClientHelper.java:293)
at com.mt.common.webclient.WebClientHelper.getAsynchronousWebClient(WebClientHelper.java:62)
at com.mt.common.webclient.test.WebClientHelperTest.testGetAsynchronousWebClientWithPathParamNotNull(WebClientHelperTest.java:216)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Code:
Junit:

```
@Test
void testGetAsynchronousWebClientWithPathParamNotNull() throws Exception {
    WebClientHelper<Stores> helper = new WebClientHelper<Stores>();
    when(webClientRequest.getRequestTracker()).thenReturn("requesttracker");
    when(webClientRequest.getPathParam()).thenReturn("pathParam");
    when(webClientRequest.getEndPoint()).thenReturn("URL");
    Map<String, String> queryParam = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    queryParam.put("Query", "select * from Stores");
    when(webClientRequest.getContentType()).thenReturn(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
    Map<String, String> headerParam = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    queryParam.put("User", "mtamp");
    when(webClientRequest.getHeadersParam()).thenReturn(headerParam);
          ClientRequest clientRequest = Mockito.mock(ClientRequest.class);
            ExchangeFunction exchangeFunction = Mockito.mock(ExchangeFunction.class);
            ClientResponse clientResponse = mock(ClientResponse.class);
    when(webClientFilter.filter(clientRequest,exchangeFunction)).thenReturn(Mono.just(clientResponse));
    
    assertNotNull(helper.getAsynchronousWebClient(webClientRequest, Stores.class));

    verify(webClientRequest, times(1)).getRequestTracker();
    verify(webClientRequest, times(2)).getHeadersParam();
    verify(webClientRequest, times(1)).getEndPoint();
    verify(webClientRequest, times(3)).getContentType();
    verify(webClientRequest, times(2)).getPathParam();

}
```

WebClientHelper.java

```
@Autowired
WebClientFilter webClientFilter;

private WebClient webClientBuilder() {
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, WebClientConstants.WEB_CLIENT_TIMEOUT)
            .responseTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(WebClientConstants.WEB_CLIENT_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT))
            .doOnConnected(conn -> conn
                    .addHandlerLast(
                            new ReadTimeoutHandler(WebClientConstants.WEB_CLIENT_READ_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                    .addHandlerLast(new WriteTimeoutHandler(WebClientConstants.WEB_CLIENT_WRITE_TIMEOUT,
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));
    return WebClient.builder()
             .filter(webClientFilter).filter(
                    ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(this::errorHandler))
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient)).build();

}
```

WebFilter.java

```
@Component
public class WebClientFilter implements ExchangeFilterFunction {


@Autowired
MtExchangeFilterFunction exchangeFilter;

    
@Override
public Mono<ClientResponse> filter(ClientRequest clientRequest, ExchangeFunction next) {
    return exchangeFilter.filter(clientRequest, next);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like you don't give your helper the WebClientFilter.

Comment: @tgdavies Can you please elaborate on your comment

Comment: WebClientHelper has a field containing a WebClientFilter. You create a mock WebClientFilter somewhere, but you don't pass it to the WebClientHelper constructor.

Comment: alternatively, if you have this WebClientFilter as a filed of the test class you can annotate it with `@MockedBean` instead of `@Mock`.